# Sort array that has different types in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I tried to run this code to sort an array and got this error

```
| x sortedX |
x := #('bb' 10 'aa' 2 'cc' 3 5).
sortedX := x asSortedCollection: [:y :z |
    (y class = z class)
        ifTrue: [y < z]
        ifFalse: [y class < z class]
].
Transcript show: sortedX; cr.
```

Expected to get `#(2 3 5 10 ‘aa’ ‘bb’ ‘cc’)`, but got error: ByteString Class(Object)>>DoesNotUnderstand

Comment: In the `false` branch you are comparing two classes with `<` and classes do not understand the `<` message. Depending on what you are trying to do, you could instead say `y class name < z class name`, as strings do understand `<`.

Comment: I tried this:     'ifFalse: [y class name < z class name]' and get 'a SortedCollection('aa' 'bb' 'cc' 2 3 5 10)', which shows strings before integers.
Instead of #(2 3 5 10 ‘aa’ ‘bb’ ‘cc’), which should be printed. Why is that?

Comment: I suspect the answer is in the error you're getting (at the end of your question, what class name is mentioned?), but you can always inspect the result or step through the code. :-)

Comment: I get the desired result because in my Smalltalk dialect those strings are instances of `String`. In your case, they are instances of `ByteString`. In both cases the integers are instances of `SmallInteger`. So, in your case `'ByteString' < 'SmallInteger'` and in my `'SmallInteger' < 'String'`. In any case, relying on the object's class is hardly a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that doesn't depend on classes

```
x := #('bb' 10 'aa' 2 'cc' 3 5).
sortedX := x asSortedCollection: [:y :z |
    y isInteger = z isInteger
        ifTrue: [y < z]
        ifFalse: [y isInteger]].
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the following is more idiomatic than the accepted answer:

```
collection := #('bb' 10 'aa' 2 'cc' 3 5).
sorted := connection sorted:
    [:ea | ea isInteger asBit] ascending
        , #yourself ascending
```

Explanation:

- `asSortedCollection[:]` creates a self-sorting collection that will update itself after any change. In 95%, you will only need to create a `sorted[:]` copy of the array (or in some occasions, `sort[:]` the array inline if you don't mind about side effects).
- Use `SortFunction`s (`ascending`, `descending`, `undefinedFirst`, `reversed`, etc.) instead of two-arg sort blocks for expressing desired order in a more declarative way. For huge (and only huge) collections, check whether it affects performance.
- `asBit` converts booleans into numbers (0 and 1ö and thus creates a natural order.